# Автоматические действия на сайте

Tags: php, javascript, apache, cross-domain

Есть сайт с формой отправки некоторых данных. С помощью чего можно реализовать заполнение и отправку этой формы из другого сайта? Допустим, на сайте `http://example1.ex11` есть форма ввода. Пользователь вводит там некоторые данные. После этого мне нужно взять эти данные и заполнить в форме на сайте `http://example2.ex22` и сделать `submit`. И все это в фоновом режиме. Средствами сервера.

Возможна ли вообще такая реализация?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы попробывал ajax. Если есть доступ к базе обоих сайтов.

Форма 1 отправляет информацию, которая хранится где-то на сервере, в базе данных, например.
Форма 2 находится в ждущем режиме: регалярно проверяет, если ли в базе информация из Формы 1. Если есть - заполнить поля.